# How to get memory dump on Azure Functions on Linux plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions

On Windows plan there is an option to take a memory dump:

[image]

However, this option is missing on Linux plan:

[image]

The option which is available for [App Services on Linux](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/11/01/Diagnostic-Tools-for-ASP-NET-Core-Linux-apps-are-now-publicly-available.html) is not available for Azure Functions on Linux.

Is there a way to get memory dumps for Azure Functions on Linux?

Comment: What is the runtime are you using

Comment: I use dotnet 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get memory dumps for Azure Functions on Linux?

- *After researching in my local environment came to a conclusion that we can't take memory dump in Azure Functions with the Linux platform.*

[image]

- *And as per the below mentioned answer from Microsoft and many other documents provides only information about memory dump with Windows Platform.*

[image]

- *So, I would even suggest you raise a [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/search/?q=azure%20functions) so that it would be helpful for the other members with related issue.*

Comment: Following your [suggestions](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/cffe995a-e51e-ed11-a81b-6045bd853198) I added the feature request. Please upvote it if you read this comment :D